# Force.com Migration Tool - Standard Quickactions not found during deployment

Tags: force.com, metadata-api, migration-tool

I am trying to deploy between sandboxes using the Force.com migration tool but keep getting build failures because the standard Case quickactions (Case.Email, Case.ChangeStatus, etc) used on certain page layouts are not being found. The errors look like:

> layouts/.layout -- Error: In field: QuickAction - no
>   QuickAction named Case.Email found

The only way I can resolve this is to remove the references to these quickactions from the metadata, run the deployment, and then manually add the actions to the page layouts in in the target org. When you add the actions back in, the metadata that is generated is exactly the same as that which failed during the build.

Any help/ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: QuickAction components are available in API version 28.0 and later, check in which version you are extracting metadata to deploy\

Comment: Hi Harshit, thanks for your response. I was using API version 31.0 and have now tried with 33.0 but still no luck. The standard quick actions don't seem to be retrieved, but this seems to be standard behaviour.

Comment: Can you fetch actions or not? Are you migrating them together with the layouts or just the layouts (as the actions might already be there)?

Comment: I am fetching the actions, however I don't seem to be able to fetch the standard actions (i.e. Case.Email). I am deploying the page layouts and the actions I can fetch at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue and fixed it as follow:

- Go to Setup > Administer > Email Administration > Deliverability
- Set the “Access level” field to “All email”

Then running the exact same deployment worked fine.